# webpack Module not found: Error: Can't resolve classNames

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

1. React + TypeScript
2. package.json

   ```
   {

   "license": "MIT",
   "keywords": [
       "react",
       "typescript"
   ],
   "peerDependencies": {
       "react": "16.13.1"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
       "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
       "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
       "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
       "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
       "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.1",
       "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
       "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.25.0",
       "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.25.0",
       "babel-jest": "^25.2.3",
       "eslint": "^6.8.0",
       "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
       "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
       "jest": "^25.2.3",
       "react": "^16.3.0",
       "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
       "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
       "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
       "ts-jest": "^25.2.1",
       "ts-loader": "^6.2.2",
       "typescript": "^3.8.3",
       "webpack": "^4.4.1",
       "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
       "webpack-stream": "^5.1.1"
   },
   "dependencies": {
       "@types/classnames": "^2.2.10",
       "@types/lodash.escaperegexp": "^4.1.6",
       "@types/nanoid": "^2.1.0",
       "@types/prop-types": "^15.7.3",
       "@types/react": "^16.9.26",
       "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Directories tree

> ```
>     .
> ├── README.org
> ├── babel.config.js
> ├── dist
> │   ├── bundle.js
> │   └── bundle.js.map
> ├── index.html
> ├── jest.config.js
> ├── node_modules [627 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
> ├── package-lock.json
> ├── package.json
> ├── src
> │   ├── component
> │   │   ├── Action.tsx
> │   │   ├── DualListBox.tsx
> │   │   ├── Filter.tsx
> │   │   ├── ListBox.tsx
> │   │   ├── lang
> │   │   ├── shapes
> │   │   └── util
> │   ├── index.tsx
> │   ├── less
> │   │   └── react-dual-listbox.less
> │   └── scss
> │       └── react-dual-listbox.scss
> ├── tree.txt
> ├── tsconfig.json
> └── webpack.config.js
>
> 9 directories, 18 files
> ```

4. webpack.config.js

> ```
>     // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
>     const path = require('path');
>
>     module.exports = {
>         mode: "development",
>
>         devtool: "source-map",
>
>         entry: './src/index.tsx',
>         module: {
>             rules: [
>                 {
>                     test: /\.(t|j)sx?$/,
>                     use: ['ts-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
>                     exclude: /node_modules/,
>                 },
>                 {
>                     enforce: "pre",
>                     test: /\.js$/,
>                     exclude: /node_modules/,
>                     loader: "source-map-loader",
>                 },
>                 {
>                     enforce: "pre",
>                     test: /\.js$/,
>                     exclude: /node_modules/,
>                     loader: "eslint-loader",
>                 }
>             ]
>         },
>         resolve: {
>             extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', 'jsx'],
>         },
>         output: {
>             filename: 'bundle.js',
>             path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
>         },
>         externals: {
>             "react": "React",
>             "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
>             // "nanoid": "nanoid",
>             // "classnames": "classNames",
>             // "lodash.escaperegexp": "escapeRegExp"
>         }
>     };
> ```
>
> `http-server ./` and in Brower console:
>
> `external "classNames":1`
>
> `Uncaught ReferenceError: classNames is not defined`

Updated:
I still didn't figure out what broken, the cdn ways fixed `classNames` problem but there is still `nanoid` error, and also [this issue](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/issues/127#issue-450077950) posted, maybe there is something wrong in `webpack.config.json`, since I don't understand what is webpack and how it works

thanks @Hassaan Tauqir and @Klas Mellbourn

**Updated**: I modified `external`field

> webpack --display-error-details

```
ERROR in ./src/component/DualListBox.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nanoid' in '/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/src/component'
resolve 'nanoid' in '/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/src/component'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/package.json (relative path: ./src/component)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/src/component/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/bunny/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/nanoid)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules
        No description file found
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoid doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoid.tsx doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoid.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        No description file found
        no extension
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoid.js doesn't exist
            jsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoid doesn't exist
        .tsx
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoidjsx doesn't exist
          /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoid.tsx doesn't exist
        .ts
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            as directory
              /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoid doesn't exist
          /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoid.ts doesn't exist
        .js
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoid.js doesn't exist
        jsx
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoidjsx doesn't exist
        as directory
          /Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoid doesn't exist
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/src/component/node_modules]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/src/node_modules]
[/Users/bunny/node_modules]
[/Users/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/package.json]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoid]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoid.tsx]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoid.ts]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoid/package.json]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoid.js]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoid]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/ts/node_modules/nanoidjsx]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoid.tsx]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoid.ts]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoid.js]
[/Users/bunny/SakurajimaMai/node_modules/nanoidjsx]
 @ ./src/component/DualListBox.tsx 7:0-28 52:35-41
 @ ./src/index.tsx
```

same errors with `@types/nanoid` and `@types/lodash.escaperegexp`

Comment: Why are you adding classnames in externals? Are you using a CDN to import it? Also, the name of the package is classnames and not classNames, so it should be externals: { "classnames": "classnames" }. Please read this doc. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#root

Comment: @HassaanTauqir 

I tried `externals: {'classnames': 'classnames'}` and open the chrome console and then
**classnames** is not found

Comment: I must ask again, why are you using externals? I think the error is there because classnames is not part of your bundle anymore. Also, please provide a full error with stack trace if possible.

Comment: It's in my `node_modules`, and I like install modules locally, thank you very much, maybe that's my configure problems @HassaanTauqir

Comment: using externals will remove a package from your webpack bundle, therefore it will not be available at run-time, unless you are using a CDN or external source to make it available in your runtime environment, see the link provided in the first comment, you would need to remove externals if you are using a package inside your node_modules.

Comment: @HassaanTauqir (crying...)
I didn''t find `@types/classnames` in cdnjs.com

Comment: you should look into https://create-react-app.dev/, it comes with a configured webpack and an option to use typescript as well. Also, I hope you were able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are really interested in low level optimizations, you shouldn't have to fiddle with stuff like webpack these days. To quickly create a react app, use [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/). Like this (specifying that you want TypeScript):

```
npx create-react-app --template typescript project-name
```

then

```
cd project-name
yarn add classnames
yarn add -D @types/classnames
yarn start
```

Then start adding code that uses `classnames`

Using that method, I've set up [a project with a working usage of classnames](https://github.com/Mellbourn/create-react-app-typesscript-classname)

Comment: need `classnames` besides `@types/classnames`? Let me try it

Comment: ok, I done it with `npm i classnames --save` and `tsc` , `npx-webpack` and then **classames** is not defined, no **n** I am sure that

Comment: If you want a react and typsecript project that works well without a hassle, I would highly recommend create-react-app, https://create-react-app.dev/. You can install it like this `npx create-react-app --template typescript project-name`.

Comment: Using that method, I've set up a project with a working usage of `classnames` here https://github.com/Mellbourn/create-react-app-typesscript-classname